# How to read mutation response from cache in Apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a login mutation, which returns:
Mutation response:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnFhn.png (it doesn't matter actually)

How can I read it from cache within another component (e.g. in `<Header />` via `readQuery()`), if it's only allowed to get queries responses this way? I don't want to create another query round-trip to reach for the data.

By the way, Apollo Dev Tools shows as if the mutation response presents in the cache with the ID as key

Are there other ways to archive this, or, maybe, I'm missing sometime?

Comment: just try to use `readQuery` ... 'mutation' is only naming convention, no real difference to 'query'

Comment: however, how to preserve the initial mutation payload?

Comment: `readFragment` instead?

Comment: mutation response can be saved in apollo local app state (@client) - to be queried anywhere